# Перенос проекта из DirectDraw в DirectX (Direct2D)

Tags: c++, directx, radstudio

Есть очень крупный проект и в нем есть файл на 6к строк, в котором описаны различные функции отрисовок (в основном графиков в реальном времени) с использованием DirectDraw(писалась лет 10 назад под xp). Встал вопрос о переносе на Win7. Начал искать информацию как и с чем тот DirecDraw есть. На [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw) сказано, что библиотека устарела и ее слили с DirectX`ом. Собственно сам вопрос, можно ли как-то перенести этот проект отделавшись малой кровью? Может быть кто сталкивался с подобным или знает сохранились ли, или хотя бы как именно видоизменились старые API. За ранее спасибо.

Comment: На сколько знаю, DirectX обратно совместимая, т.е. должно и так заработать.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian проблема в том, что DirectDraw требовал подключения ddutil.h, которого в DirectX_SDK нет. Может быть вы знаете, что подключать вместо него?

Comment: Посмотрел только, что ddutil.h отсутствует в DireсtX7 SDK, может это какой-то кастомный (с таким же названием есть файл в примерах этого SDK).

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian не в 7-й версии, а начиная с 7-й. У меня Microsoft DirectX SDK (2010 June), в котором тоже нет ddutil.h и иже с ним

Comment: Странно, т.к. DirectX7 вышел раньше чем WindowsXP.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но насколько я помню ddutil не входил в состав библиотеки, он кажется из примеров брался. Поэтому можно поробовать поискать в интернетах, обязательно кто-то забекапил.

Comment: Вот ваш ddutil http://gamemake.narod.ru/ddutil.html

Comment: @Cerbo я же написал, что у меня есть проект который нужно перенести, очевидно у меня есть ddutil.h и ddraw.lib. Грубо говоря в 6 билдере собирается проект, а в rad xe8 нет, потому и начал искать информацию по поводу переноса на directx. Единственное что нашёл по теме, так вот это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201775/what-to-use-instead-directdraw , но там описан процесс создания приложения с нуля, я же ищу информацию по переносу проекта

Comment: @dr_zak DirectDraw хоть и объявлен утсаревшим, но никуда не делся. То есть вожно по-прежнему под ним новые проекты разрабатывать. Лучше поясните что конкретно у вас не получается, уверен что проблема не в DirectDraw.

Comment: @Cerbo в общем, с помощью Интернета смог скомпилировать и запустить проект. Вся часть несвязанная с отрисовкой(DirectDraw) работает, так как и должна, но даже самый простой режим, просто отрисовка осей и рисок на них, никак не хочет заводится, выдаёт 'Access violation at address ... in module Program.exe. Read of address 00000000

Comment: Почему-то DDLoadBitmap возвращает null, не может подгрузить битмап из ресурсов, оттого не создаются нужные для дальнейшей отрисовки поверхности и проект обращается к несуществующим объектам и умирает. Хотя все сделано так как и в старом проекте.